# Java Scanner won't read

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read from a file that has information written in the format:
someName:aDoubleNumber
and returns the name and the double.
I've written the following scanner, but it doesn't work, any ideas why?

```
Scanner readFile = new Scanner("text.txt");
readFile.useDelimiter(":");
while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
String name = readFile.next();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? (From the looks of it you are not trying to read in any doubles.)

Comment: It says it can't find the readFile package. And I don't know how to get it to read the doubles.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: You must try more thing before asking, also you must search other questions with similar problems and explain what you have done in your question. Try to do better questions that can help others not only you.

Answer (score 7):

You're not reading from a file. You're reading the String "text.txt". You need a file first.

```
    Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File("text.txt")); // don't forget to catch FileNotFoundException!
    readFile.useDelimiter(":|\\n");
    while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
       String name = readFile.next();
       double value = readFile.nextDouble();
       System.out.println(name + " " + value);
    }
```

I took the code from your comment and formatted, and I get this

```
public class MyProject { 
    class FileInput { 
        Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File("text.txt")); // don't forget to catch FileNotFoundException! 
        readFile.useDelimiter(":|\\n"); 
        while (fileScanner.hasNext()) { 
            String name = readFile.next(); 
            double value = readFile.nextDouble(); 
            System.out.println(name + " " + value); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Now you seem to have a problem - perhaps you meant `class FileInput` to be `public void fileInput() throws Exception`? When I do this, it compiles. Now we need a `main()` method to run it! So I add this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyProject proj = new MyProject();
    proj.fileInput();
}
```

Now when I ran it I actually got an error. This means there was actually a problem in the code I gave you to begin with. Of course, that code was never intended to be copy/pasted, but was more to give an idea of capability. Anyway, the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2387)
    at MyProject.fileInput(MyProject.java:9) <--- Where it happened in our code
    at MyProject.main(MyProject.java:16)
```

The line where it happened was on the parseDouble. So, instead, let's try doing it a different way. We can get the double as a raw piece of text, and then parse it into an actual double like this:

```
    while (readFile.hasNext()) { 
        String name = readFile.next(); 
        String valueStr = readFile.next();
        double value = Double.parseDouble(valueStr); 
        System.out.println(name + " " + value); 
    }
```

So the whole completed program is:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MyProject { 
    public void fileInput() throws Exception { 
        Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File("text.txt")); // don't forget to catch FileNotFoundException! 
        readFile.useDelimiter(":|\\n"); 
        while (readFile.hasNext()) { 
            String name = readFile.next(); 
            String valueStr = readFile.next();
            double value = Double.parseDouble(valueStr); 
            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            System.out.println("Value: " + value);
            System.out.println(""); // blank line
        } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyProject proj = new MyProject();
        proj.fileInput();
    }
```

So for the input file text being:

```
this:1234.5
that:321.0
the other:0.122
```

The output was

```
C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java MyProject
Name: this
Value: 1234.5

Name: that
Value: 321.0

Name: the other
Value: 0.122


C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java MyProject
}
```

Comment: Right now, my code looks like: public class MyProject { class FileInput { Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File("text.txt")); // don't forget to catch FileNotFoundException!
    readFile.useDelimiter(":|\\n");
    while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
       String name = readFile.next();
       double value = readFile.nextDouble();
       System.out.println(name + " " + value);
    }
}} but I get an exception. Sorry about this (I'm learning from a book)

Comment: Update your question with 1) Your new code and 2) the exact copy/paste exception notice you get.

Comment: @James, I updated my answer with respect to your most recent comment here. Let me know if you still have any questions about this.